# Get the thumbnail of the uploaded video programmatically

Tags: 8, entities

I have a content type include a file field for uploading videos, what I want to do is to get the thumbnail of the uploaded video automatically from my custom module.

Comment: Jeeze, how about giving more details. Such as, what Drupal Core version are you using? 7 or 8? Are you using the Media module?

Comment: I'm sorry to forget that it's a version 8 and I don't use media module

Comment: We don't write tutorials for vague requirements - where are you stuck? Can you update the question with the code you're currently trying and detail what's not working?

Comment: sorry, but I was asking for a way or there is a Drupal built-in function doing that. BTW, I've solved it using PHP FFmpeg contrib mobule

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved it by using [PHP FFmpeg](https://www.drupal.org/project/php_ffmpeg)

`$ffmpeg = Drupal::service('php_ffmpeg');
$video = $ffmpeg->open('sample.mp4');
$video
->frame(FFMpeg\Coordinate\TimeCode::fromSeconds(1))
->save('frame.jpg');`